# SQL how to clean and create following table?

Tags: sql, datatables, etl

This is the first time that I post a question, but I could not find any answer from Data Experts. What I want to know is, if it is possible to create a table only with SQL?

The initial table:

[image]

In CSV Format:
Ereignisname;Zeitstempel
Prozess ID;
10100;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-08-08T22:52:00
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-08-12T13:04:32
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-08-16T02:20:50
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-08-22T05:18:50
Prozess ID;
10101;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-07-12T13:30:43
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-07-15T07:15:50
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-07-19T08:03:39
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-08-06T01:47:13
Prozess ID;
10102;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-06-26T17:33:15
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-06-29T18:13:02
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-07-03T21:18:53
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-07-16T04:29:57
Prozess ID;
10103;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-09-23T05:51:49
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-09-26T12:21:05
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-09-28T17:17:19
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-10-14T17:59:32
Prozess;
10104;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-07-28T21:41:26
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-07-31T05:43:01
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-08-03T21:11:49
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-08-19T04:55:26

How this table should be modified with SQL:

[image]

Many thanks in advance

Kind regards
George

Comment: Hi George what database are working on and what do you mean saying "only with SQL"?

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the last record in your expected results view?

Comment: Hi George, Could you please be more clear?, when you say 'create a table only with SQL'. do you need a SQL script to create a table with above mentioned values?

Comment: @ekochergin Hi Ekochergin, sorry for the delayed answer! It is just an a simple Excel file. What I meant was, how can I modify the original table and add the process ID as a new column in SQL? I could solve that in VBA, but in SQL I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @RossBush Yes, I did like that, because sometimes the processes might be done or skep in different secuences

Comment: @Annamalai Hi Annamalai, exactly! That is what I meant, I could solve this in VBA, but in SQL no one told me, if that was possible. Therefore I just want to know if a looping is possible in SQL and how it would look like.

Comment: You can do this... it'll probably be a couple of statements in a stored procedure though. Are you asking for how to attempt it, or someone to write the code for you? Which version of sql are thinking of using?

Comment: @George, are you trying to automate the process? Read from Excel and write it into SQL table. Or you just need a script to create table with above mentioned values for just One time.

Comment: @George, Where is your initial table resides? is it in excel.

Comment: @Monofuse Hi Monofuse, what I wanted to know if it was possible in SQL. Not the complete code, but at least the Loop (For or while) for identifying the Process ID and then create the new column related to original table.

Comment: @Annamalai Yes, but to automate the process is possible only in SQL. I couldn't solve this, I prepare the data unfortunately in VBA. Initial Table was a csv file, which can be imported into this environment and extract the data via SQL.

Comment: Hi @George, the initial table doesn't seem to be in CSV format, you can check out SSIS. If your real intention is to dump your data from CSV to SQL, because the structure of initial table you posted neither in SQL nor in CSV format.

Comment: @Annamalai of course, and unfortunately it was worst than this format. With Celonis you can import the csv and start to modify it with SQL in order to create the desired table (3 columns, namely: process ID, activity and timestamp). However, I am new in SQL and I don't know how or what must done e.g. same table and join it with a copy of the same table and how? Or is there any Loop option (for, while) in SQL?

Comment: @Annamalai I think we got distracted with the CSV formatting. My mistake it was actually always in CSV format. What would be the approach to solve this in SQL and to create the desire table? This is the format Ereignisname;Zeitstempel
Prozess ID;
10100;
Kundenbestellung eingegangen;2017-08-08T22:52:00
Bezahlung erhalten;2017-08-12T13:04:32
Per Standardversand verschicken;2017-08-16T02:20:50
Versandbestaetigung erhalten;2017-08-22T05:18:50

Comment: If you have the CSV file, you can use ```BULK INSERT``` to insert it into the table or you use ```SSIS``` to export the data to a sql table.

Comment: please share your csv data if possible, what ever you shared is not csv data, csv data will have comma as a separator. and even the header row is missing.

Comment: @Annamalai  Yes, you are right, in USA, but in Germany it uses semicolon for CSV formatting. But, how can I convert the rows with the content "10100", "10101","10102","10103","10104" into columns until the word "Prozess ID" is found, then and the next "Prozess ID"? Is this possible with BULK INSERT or SSIS?

Comment: @George, Sorry! I don't think I know any ways to import csv with uneven columns in SQL (as per my knowledge), you should probably first fix the csv format (as you said 'in VBA') then you can export it to a SQL Table.

Comment: @Annamalai I didn't see this comment. Yes, that was original question, if it is possible to transform tables in SQL. Sorry from my side, my english might not be good to formulate correctly the question. Until now, even other guys from data science told to use Python or Pandas for doing it and apparently is not possible ins SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `csv` file and expecting to insert the data into a `SQL Table` you can use the below script to do so, or you can create a `SSIS` package dataflow to insert the data from `csv` to `SQL Table`

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable --use your table name
(ProcessId INT, Process VARCHAR(500),[TimeStamp] DATETIME)

BULK INSERT TempTable -- use your table name
FROM 'path to your csv file'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

let me know if you still need any clarification.

Comment: @Annalai wow many thanks!!! It seems to be fine and with it I can import the CSV file as the initial table.  But how do I convert the initial table and transform it into the desired table, in which the third column is added from the next row of Prozess ID?